# Fix HTMLCollection of 4 elements but it actually shows 3 of them

Tags: javascript, htmlcollection

i was refactoring my js code and it popped out a bug. The bug is that in a HTMLCollection of 4 elements (and if i console log them, they are ok), but if i loop them in a for, it shows me that the collection is actually 3 instead of 4. So for example an array of indexes (0,1,2,3), it shows (0,1,3) skipping the second element. I can't show much of the code because it's quite long and so my question is: why does this can happend?

console.log of the HTMLCollection:

```
HTMLCollection(3) [li.page-item, li#page0.page-item, li.page-item, page0: li#page0.page-item]
0: li.page-item
1: li#page0.page-item
2: li#page1.page-item
3: li.page-item
page0: li#page0.page-item
page1: li#page1.page-item
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: HTMLCollection
```

console.log of the length:

```
3
```

Html of pagination (i wrote a js function for create new li inside the div):

```
              <ul id="pagination" class="pagination flex-wrap">
                <li class="page-item"><button type="button" class="page-link" onclick="characters.deleteCharacter()">Delete</button></li>
                <li class="page-item active" id="page0" style="display: none;"><a type="button" class="page-link">0</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><button type="button" class="page-link" onclick="characters.createCharacter()">New</button></li>
              </ul>
```

Comment: (i console logged them each next to each)

Comment: How do you got the html collection? is there a dom structure?

Comment: yes, i get the collection by document.getElementById('pagination').getElementsByTagName("li")

Comment: Can you update your post with the html of `pagination`?

Comment: done, sorry for the bad indentation

Comment: I tested your code on my local and I had 3 elements. Also, are you creating elements and push it into list using `string literals`?

Comment: Or are you loading more elements using an http request?

Comment: i add li elements like that: https://pastebin.com/xcVxNWE9

Comment: if you look in the console log, there are 4 elements but 3 are showed (not the page1)

Comment: I copy your code and used into my local and I have the 4 when I add a new element. Of course, I used `appendChild` instead of `insertChildAtIndex`. how is your logic on `insertChildAtIndex`?

Comment: wait, i gave you the unrefactored code. i'll give you the refactored code of the createcharacter + insertchildatindex function: https://pastebin.com/JF3s257Z

Comment: if you want i can give the full code

Comment: that's the full code: https://pastebin.com/xbVdufA0